# Redraw events lost?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've got a pygtk app which uses gtk print_run_page_setup_dialog. For some reason, some widgets (siblings to button that invoked the dialog) are no more redrawn after closing this dialog. Forcibly calling queue_draw on them works fine.

I'd like to identify where are the events going, and reconnect them to proper location. How do I go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds incredibly unlikely that the dialog should somehow mess with event handler connections for unrelated widgets.

Make sure the dialog is not stuck in a nested main loop (the call you mention has `run` in its name, implying a call to `gtk_main()` is taking place to make the dialog modal).

Comment: I know it sounds incredible, but I found no other explanation. 
How do I check this?